# FRW bootstrap in R

Tags: regression, logistic, bootstrap, rare-events

I am working on a logistic regression problem with 2 classes (let's say 0 and 1) where the positive class (1) is rare. In this case, I have found that Fractional-Random-Weight
Bootstrap (FRW) is a good procedure for logistic regression.  I was wondering if I get clarification of:

i) FRW bootstrap concepts for logistic regression
ii) example code of FRW bootstrap in R